# Simplificar código Python que carga un xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente desarrollo en el que estoy trabajando con el módulo ElementTree y Pandas en Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

file_xml = ET.parse('example1.xml')
rootXML = file_xml.getroot()

def transfor_data_atri(rootXML):
    file_xml = ET.parse(rootXML)
    data_XML = [
        {"Name": signal.attrib["Name"],
         # "Value": signal.attrib["Value"]
         "Value": int(signal.attrib["Value"].split(' ')[0])
         } for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Signal")
    ]
    
    signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data_XML)
    extract_name_value(signals_df)
    
def extract_name_value(signals_df):
    #print(signals_df)
    
    signal_ig_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["Status"])]
    row_values_ig_st = signal_ig_st.T
    vector_ig_st = row_values_ig_st.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_nav_DSP_rq = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["SetDSP"])]
    row_values_nav_DSP_rq = signal_nav_DSP_rq.T
    vector_nav_DSP_rq = row_values_nav_DSP_rq.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_HMI_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["HMI"])]
    row_values_HMI_st = signal_HMI_st.T
    vector_HMI_st = row_values_HMI_st.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_delay_ac = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["Delay"])]
    row_values_delay_ac = signal_delay_ac.T
    vector_delay_ac = row_values_delay_ac.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_AutoConfigO_Rear = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["AutoConfigO_Rear"])]
    row_values_AutoConfigO_Rear = signal_AutoConfigO_Rear.T
    vector_AutoConfigO_Rear = row_values_AutoConfigO_Rear.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_ACO_Front = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["AutoConfigO_Front"])]
    row_values_ACO_Front = signal_ACO_Front.T
    vertor_ACO_Front = row_values_ACO_Front.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_ACO_Drvr = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["AutoConfigO_Drvr"])]
    row_values_ACO_Drvr = signal_ACO_Drvr.T
    vector_ACO_Drvr = row_values_ACO_Drvr.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_ACO_Allst = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["AutoConfigO_Allst"])]
    row_values_ACO_Allst = signal_ACO_Allst.T
    vector_ACO_Allst = row_values_ACO_Allst.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_RURRq_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["RUResReqstStat"])]
    row_values_RURRq_st = signal_RURRq_st.T
    vector_RURRq_st = row_values_RURRq_st.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_RURqSy_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["RUReqstrSystem"])]
    row_values_RURqSy_st = signal_RURqSy_st.T
    vector_RURqSy_st = row_values_RURqSy_st.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_RUAudS_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["RUSource"])]
    row_values_RUAudS_st = signal_RUAudS_st.T
    vector_RUAudS_st = row_values_RUAudS_st.iloc[[1]]
    
    signal_DSP_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["DSP"])]
    row_values_DSP = signal_DSP.T
    vector_DSP = row_values_DSP.iloc[[1]]
    
    print('1: ', vector_ig_st)
    print('2: ', vector_nav_DSP_rq)
    print('3: ', vector_HMI_st)
    print('4: ', vector_delay_ac)
    # print('5: ', vector_AutoConfigO_Rear)
    # print('6: ', vertor_ACO_Front)
    # print('7: ', vector_ACO_Drvr)
    # print('8: ', vector_ACO_Allst)
    # print('9: ', vector_RURRq_st)
    # print('10: ', vector_RURqSy_st)
    # print('11: ', vector_RUAudS_st)
    # print('12: ', vector_DSP)
```

El resultado de lo anterior es el siguiente, son las primeros 4 print y está bien, porque es lo que se quiere, pero tengo que **simplificar el código, para cualquier otro archivo xml** del tipo: [link a xml extenso](https://github.com/MR/blob/master/example1.xml), y pueda leerse, no solo example1.xml:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realicé la prueba con el siguiente código, pero en todos los casos, los print me sale el resultado por separado:

```
    signals_name = signals_df["Name"]
    # print(signals_name)
    row_signals_name = signals_name.T
    # print(row_signals_name)
    for i in row_signals_name:
       print(i)
```

He estado revisando que Pandas guarda el DataFrame como una matriz, pero no encuentro como revisar esa matriz para hacer que me salgan los nombres en una variable del tipo:

```
        names_list = [
            'Status', 'SetDSP', 'HMI', 'Delay', 'AutoConfigO_Rear',
            'AutoConfigO_Front', 'AutoConfigO_Drvr','AutoConfigO_Allst',
            'RUResReqstStat', 'RUReqstrSystem', 'RUSource', 'DSP' 
        ]
```

Pero en vez de que traiga los nombres harcodeados `'Status', 'SetDSP', 'HMI', 'Delay', etc` o las comparaciones de pandas `.isin(["Status"]), .isin(["SetDSP"])], etc` me los traiga fucionados o simplificados en una variable dentro del código Python (o quitar lo repetitivo de esta función), para que cuando el cliente quiera usar otro archivo XML con la misma estructura, pero con otros nombres que no están en el código hardcodeado, la función extract_name_value(signals_df) pueda leerlos sin problema. Alguien podría compartirme un ejemplo de como se itera, por fa? Cualquier comentario ayuda. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: si iteras en el propio dataframe te devuelve el nombre de las columnas, con eso ya tienes los nombres, solo seleccionas los datos que quieras

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Christian... No se si lo estoy haciendo mal, pero creo que eso que me dices, es la prueba que comento que hice y que me sale por separado:  
`for i in can_signals.Name:
  print(i)`

Comment: Es `for col in df: print(col)`, voy a ver si hago una respuesta

Comment: @Christian pensé por un rato el primer comentario que me hiciste de iterar el propio dataframe, lo apliqué de la siguiente forma y ya me imprime la salida como me la imprime en el código largo de la pregunta, o sea, funcionó:
        `for i in can_signals.Name:
             # print(i)
             signal = can_signals[can_signals.Name.isin([i])]
             row_values = signal.T
             vector = row_values.iloc[[1]]
             print(vector)`
Te agradezco mucho.

Comment: De igual forma hago la respuesta simplificando todo?o ya no es necesario?

Comment: Ya no es necesario, tu primer respuesta me dió la solución, pero podemos hablar por el chat?. Muchisimas gracias.